# How to split the tooltip content to two columns if there is too much data

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I am using Chart.js and have a tooltip on my charts.

```
 plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        caretSize: 10,
        cornerRadius: 30,
        bodySpacing: 10,
        mode: "index",
        usePointStyle: true,
        boxWidth: 10,
        boxHeight: 10,
        boxPadding: 10,
        padding: 20,
        intersect: false,
        titleFont: {
          size: CHART_STYLE_CONFIG.tooltipTitleFontSize,
        },
        titleColor: COLORS.TEXT_PRIMARY,
        bodyFont: {
          size: CHART_STYLE_CONFIG.tooltipBodyFontSize,
          weight: 400,
        },
        bodyColor: COLORS.TEXT_PRIMARY,
        backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
      },
```

Some of my charts contain a large amount of data. I want to widen the tooltip and split the data into two columns. (see the attached image) Is this possible? https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wepC.png